# RecyclerView pagination [Omnidirectional]

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

> Making a RecyclerView pagination work in 2 directions.

Use pagination while moving up and down. *i.e* Fetch records when it reaches the end and also when it reaches the top. Somehow I end up with incorrect page numbers *(track of the first visible item and last visible item index positions)*

---

Say I have 10 thousand records **[The Pool]** to display. I can't keep all this data in memory and I can not display all the records at once in a `RecyclerView`. So, my approach is to keep few hundred records **[The window]** in the `RecyclerView.Adapter` at any time and query the `next` and `previous` data on reaching the **endpoints**.
[image: Task]

### I've come up with code and It works but for some reasons unknown *`[The BUG]`* I end up with incorrect `last page` and `first page`, causing the adapter to have duplicate data.

---

## 1. getScrollListener()

`Manager` is just a class that is used for configuration presets.
`onLoadNext` called when recyclerView reaches the bottom end.

### `onLoadPrev` called when recycler reaches the top end.

```
private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener getScrollListener(final EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener.Manager manager) {

return new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(manager, recyclerViewPhotos.getLayoutManager()) {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
    @Override
    public void onLoadNext(final int page, int totalItemsCount, final RecyclerView view) {
        System.out.println(">>>>> LOAD NEXT PAGE " + page + " total " + totalItemsCount);

        AsyncTask<Object, Integer, MinimalPhotoWithUser[]> task = new AsyncTask<Object, Integer, MinimalPhotoWithUser[]>() {
            int offset;
            int limit;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                offset = page * PER_PAGE;
                limit = PER_PAGE;
            }

            @Override
            protected MinimalPhotoWithUser[] doInBackground(Object... args) {
                final long lastPhoto_ID = photosAdapter.getLastDisplayedPhotoId(dbHelper);
                Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchPhotoRecordsAfterID(lastPhoto_ID, PER_PAGE);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    return MinimalPhotoWithUser.photoWithUsers(cursor);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final MinimalPhotoWithUser[] photos) {
                if (photos != null && photos.length > 0) {
                    recyclerViewPhotos.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            photosAdapter.appendSamples(photos);
                            loadNextComplete();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    fetchPhotosFromWeb();
                }
            }
        };
        // execute
        task.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadPrev(final int page, int totalItemsCount, final RecyclerView view) {
        System.out.println(">>>>> LOAD PREV PAGE " + page + " total " + totalItemsCount);

        if (page < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no more prev pages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        AsyncTask<Object, Integer, MinimalPhotoWithUser[]> task = new AsyncTask<Object, Integer, MinimalPhotoWithUser[]>() {
            int offset;
            int limit;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                offset = page * PER_PAGE;
                limit = PER_PAGE;
            }

            @Override
            protected MinimalPhotoWithUser[] doInBackground(Object... args) {
                final long lastPhoto_ID = photosAdapter.getFirstDisplayedPhotoId(dbHelper);
                Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchPhotoRecordsBeforeID(lastPhoto_ID, PER_PAGE);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    return MinimalPhotoWithUser.photoWithUsers(cursor);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final MinimalPhotoWithUser[] photos) {
                if (photos != null) {
                    recyclerViewPhotos.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            photosAdapter.prependSamples(photos);
                            loadPrevComplete();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        // execute
        task.execute();
    }
};
```

## 2. EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener a RecyclerView.OnScrollListener subclass

---

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {


    private final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


    public static class Manager {
        /// start page of the window
        private final int startPage = 0;
        // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
        // before loading more.
        private int visibleThreshold = 5;
        private final int window;
        private final int perPage;
        // end page of the window
        private int endPage;
        // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
        boolean loadingPrev = false;
        boolean loadingNext = false;

        public Manager(int window, int perPage, int endPage) {
            this.window = window;
            this.perPage = perPage;
            this.endPage = endPage;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "startPage: " + startPage +
                    " visibleThreshold: " + visibleThreshold +
                    " window: " + window +
                    " perPage: " + perPage +
                    " endPage: " + endPage +
                    " loadingPrev: " + loadingPrev +
                    " loadingNext: " + loadingNext;
        }
    }

    private Manager manager;

    public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(Manager manager, RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        if (layoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
            manager.visibleThreshold = manager.visibleThreshold * ((GridLayoutManager) layoutManager).getSpanCount();
        } else if (layoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
            manager.visibleThreshold = manager.visibleThreshold * ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) layoutManager).getSpanCount();
        }
    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }

    public int getFirstVisibleItem(int[] firstVisibleItemPositions) {
        int minSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < firstVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                minSize = firstVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return minSize;
    }

    // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
    // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
    // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = 0;
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

        if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
            int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
            // get maximum element within the list
            lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);

            int[] firstVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPositions(null);
            // get maximum element within the list
            firstVisibleItemPosition = getFirstVisibleItem(firstVisibleItemPositions);

        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            firstVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            firstVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        }

        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount == 0) {
            resetState();
        }

        // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadNext to fetch the data.
        // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
        if (!manager.loadingPrev) {
            if (dy < 0 && (firstVisibleItemPosition - manager.visibleThreshold) <= 0 && totalItemCount > 0) {
                if (manager.endPage > 0) {
                    manager.endPage--;
                }
                manager.loadingPrev = true;
                manager.loadingNext = false;
                onLoadPrev(getCurrentPageFromTop(), totalItemCount, view);
            }
        }

        if (!(manager.loadingNext)) {
            if (dy > 0 && (lastVisibleItemPosition + manager.visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
                manager.endPage++;
                manager.loadingNext = true;
                manager.loadingPrev = false;
                onLoadNext(manager.endPage, totalItemCount, view);
            }
        }
    }

    private int getCurrentPageFromTop() {
        int value = manager.endPage - manager.window;
        if (value < 0) {
            value = -1;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public int getEndPage() {
        return manager.endPage;
    }


    public final void loadNextComplete() {
        manager.loadingNext = false;
    }

    public final void loadPrevComplete() {
        manager.loadingPrev = false;
    }

    public boolean isLoadingNext() {
        return manager.loadingNext;
    }

    public boolean isLoadingPrev() {
        return manager.loadingPrev;
    }



    // Call this method whenever performing new searches
    // FixMe: Come up with something better
    public void resetState() {
        manager.loadingNext = false;
        manager.loadingPrev = false;
    }

    public abstract void onLoadPrev(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadNext(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);

}
```

*[Note: This code typically displays photos and the code related to photos checks the database if data after current position exists then it fetches the records from database otherwise records are fetched from network request and then added to the database and the adapter]*

Comment: can u tell me the page item

Comment: I did not understand the context of your question but I at the moment recyclerview displays images if this is what you are asking. @Nilu

Comment: what no of records you want to display in one page inside recyclerview

Comment: Can be any number. `window ` variable in `Manager` class.